# How to creat mutiple UserProfiles that inherit from AbstractUser in Django?

Tags: python, django

Original Question

I want to create 3 UserProfile for 3 types of users. At first, I made a `CharFiled` as a mark to differentiate them, but then I realized that I have to put some `ForeignKey` to associate those users. As for this step, I don't know how to make it come true.

---

To make it specific:

- 3 types of users that inherit from `AbstractUser`, each of them can log into the system
- There is a hierarchy among them, much like:

```
AdminstratorA（not a superuser）
AdminstratorB
    |--TeacherA
    |--TeacherB
         |--StudentA
         |--StudentB|
```

following  are my  failures(simplified version), Using `Django2.1` `python3.7`

- got a problem, because  I could only set  one `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.UserProfile'` at  `mysite\settings.py`

```py
apps\users\model

from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models

class AdministratorUser(AbstractUser):
    pass


class TeacherUser(AbstractUser):
    administrator = models.ForeignKey(AdministratorUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class StudentUser(AbstractUser):
    teacher = models.ForeignKey(TeacherUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

- I set the main table and other 3 tables as complement.  Based on that, I designed my admin site based on `xadmin`, and the data doesn't represent well.  I have no idea about it. So I try to redesign my model, which is the plan I described on the top.

```
apps\users\model

from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models


class UserProfile(AbstractUser):
    user_type_choices = (
        ('student', 'student'),
        ('teacher', 'teacher'),
        ('teacher', 'teacher'),
    )
    identity = models.CharField(choices=user_type_choices, max_length=100, default='student')


class AdministratorUser(models.Model):
    user_profile = models.OneToOneField(UserProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class TeacherUser(models.Model):
    user_profile = models.OneToOneField(UserProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    administrator = models.ForeignKey(AdministratorUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class StudentUser(models.Model):
    user_profile = models.OneToOneField(UserProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    teacher = models.ForeignKey(TeacherUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Comment: I understand that you are a new user but for the future please refer to [MCVE guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) by providing an example of the attempt of implementation.

Comment: I just realized that maybe I have mixed up `Django User` and `Normal User`. `Django User` can login to `Django Admin`, while `Normal User` couldn't. What I have to do in this situation is to create some`Normal Users` and one `Django User`, which is enough for my project.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends what you're trying to achieve, but the simplest approach would be similar to the `is_staff` and `is_superuser` fields in the standard `User` model.

```
class UserProfile(AbstractUser):
    is_type1_user = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_type2_user = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_type3_user = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of [Django's generic relations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#generic-relations) by customising the `User` model as well as the `UserManager` in the following way:

First of all you need to import the relevant stuff:

```
from django.apps import apps

from django.contrib.contenttypes.fields import GenericForeignKey
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
from django.contrib.contenttypes.fields import GenericRelation

from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser, UserManager as OriginalUserManager
```

The `UserManager`:

```
class UserManager(OriginalUserManager):

    def _create_user(self, username, email, password, **extra_fields):
        """
        Create and save a user with the given username, email, and password.
        """
        if not username:
            raise ValueError('The given username must be set')

        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        username = self.model.normalize_username(username)
        user = self.model(username=username, email=email, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)

        # handle profile creation at user creation
        profile_model = User.TYPE_MODELS.get(user.user_type)
        profile_model = apps.get_model(app_label='app1', model_name=profile_model)

        if profile_model is None:
            raise Exception(
                "Profile model has not been set in User.TYPE_MODELS for user type {}".format(user.user_type))

        profile = profile_model.objects.create()

        user.content_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(profile_model)
        user.object_id = profile.id
        user.content_object = profile

        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user
```

The `User` model:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    TYPE_1 = 0
    TYPE_2 = 1

    TYPE_CHOICES = (
        (TYPE_1, "Type 1"),
        (TYPE_2, "Type 2"),
    )

    TYPE_MODELS = dict((
        (TYPE_1, "ProfileType1"),
        (TYPE_2, "ProfileType2"),
    ))

    user_type = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=TYPE_CHOICES, default=TYPE_1)

    # Below the mandatory fields for generic relation
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey()

    objects = UserManager()

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('content_type', 'object_id',)

    @property
    def profile(self):
        return self.content_object
```

Then you can define your profiles as such (for example):

```
class BaseProfileModel(models.Model):
    _user = GenericRelation(User)

    @property
    def user(self):
        ctype = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(self.__class__)
        try:
            event = User.objects.get(content_type__pk=ctype.id, object_id=self.id)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return None

        return event


class ProfileType1(BaseProfileModel):
    x = models.IntegerField(default=0)


class ProfileType2(BaseProfileModel):
    y = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

Now the way you can use them is in the following way:

Create a user with a default user type:

```
user = User.objects.create_user("someusername")
user.profile --> will yield a ProfileType1 instance
```

Create a user with a secific user type

```
user = User.objects.create_user("someothername", user_type=User.TYPE_2)
user.profile --> will yield a ProfileType2 instance
```

In both cases if we have in our hands the profile instance we can obtain the user by doing:

```
profile.user --> will yield our original user instance
```